# Search markers within an Array and locate them

Tags: java, android, arrays, search, google-maps-markers

So , here is my problem:

I have a String array that I defined in my onMapReady method:

```
String [] thePlaces = {"Thirsty Monk", "Cocolino", "The Melting Pot", "De Danu", "Carciuma", "Boca", "Bar Acasa"};
```

All the strings inside the array are defined by separate markers like this:

```
 //Carciuma
    LatLng test1 = new LatLng(43.604892, 1.476562);
    mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(test1).title("Carciuma"));
```

I have the following methods declared:

```
private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom){

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
    mMap.moveCamera(update);
}

private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v){
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}


public void locateFromString(View view) {

    hideSoftKeyboard(view);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String searchString = tv.getText().toString();
```

On my map I have created a search field that I would like to perform a search only within the strings of my array. So when I push the search button to locate the marker name introduced by the user the locateFromString method is called. This method in my opinion should see if the marker introduced by the user exists in the array or not. If it exists it should locate it with the gotoLocation method if not a Toast should be displayed saying that the searched marker is not in the array.

How exactly do I have to do that? Search within the array and if the name is found to locate it ?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

UPDATE

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

GoogleMap mMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);



    assert getSupportActionBar() != null;
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.location:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.map_type:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map Type selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.share_app:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Share the APP", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;


    LatLng cityView = new LatLng(43.604346, 1.443760);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cityView, 12));


    MarkerOptions beerMarker = new MarkerOptions()
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.beer_marker));


    // The Thirsty monk
    LatLng thirstyMonk = new LatLng(43.607044, 1.450307);
    mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(thirstyMonk).title("Thirsty Monk"));
    // The Cocolino
    LatLng cocolino = new LatLng(43.571505, 1.417759);
    mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(cocolino).title("Cocolino"));
    //The Melting Pot
    LatLng meltingPot = new LatLng(43.607469, 1.447162);
    mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(meltingPot).title("The Melting Pot"));
    //De Danu
    LatLng deDanu = new LatLng(43.600723, 1.455917);
    mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(deDanu).title("De Danu"));
    //Carciuma
    LatLng test1 = new LatLng(43.604892, 1.476562);
    mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(test1).title("Carciuma"));
    //Test2
    LatLng test2 = new LatLng(43.604496, 1.474924);
    mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(test2).title("Boca"));
    //Test3
    LatLng test3 = new LatLng(43.604781, 1.474502);
    mMap.addMarker(beerMarker.position(test3).title("Bar Acasa"));

}

private void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom){

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
    mMap.moveCamera(update);
}

private void hideSoftKeyboard(View v){
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}


public void locateFromString(View view) {

    hideSoftKeyboard(view);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String searchString = tv.getText().toString();



    ArrayList<String> thePlaces = new ArrayList<>();
    thePlaces.add("Thirsty Monk");
    thePlaces.add("Cocolino");
    thePlaces.add("The Melting Pot");
    thePlaces.add("De Danu");
    thePlaces.add("Carciuma");
    thePlaces.add("Boca");
    thePlaces.add("Bar Acasa");


    ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(thePlaces));
    if (places.contains(searchString)) {



        //do something
    };

   // if (thePlaces.contains(searchString)){



    //if (searchString.length() > 0){

      //  Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for: " + searchString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //} else {
   //     Toast.makeText(this, "There is no " + searchString + " subscribed to this app!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // }


    //Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(this);


}
```

}

The last lines are some things I tried so don't mid that!

UPDATE XML 
here I have changed the EditText with Autocomplete:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.gadgetcatch.happyhourtoulouse.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/search_pub"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">


        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/search_pub"
            android:inputType="textCapWords">

            <requestFocus />
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="@string/search_go"
            android:onClick="locateFromString"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here it is the log:

04-02 19:42:08.791 11984-11984/com.gadgetcatch.happyhourtoulouse E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.gadgetcatch.happyhourtoulouse, PID: 11984
                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254) 
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.contains(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at com.gadgetcatch.happyhourtoulouse.MainActivity.locateFromString(MainActivity.java:182)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254) 
                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If converting the array to an ArrayList is not an issue - you can use the contains() method to check whether the searchString is in the list. If you want your search to be case insensitive - convert the values from the array and the searchString to uppercase/lowercase. See the following example:

```
    ...
    ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(thePlaces));
    if (places.contains(searchString)) {
        //do something
    };
```

UPDATED

Regarding the `locateFromString` method - since you already have an ArrayList `thePlaces` there is no need for `places`. Also i would suggest making `thePlaces` an instance variable, like `mMap`, and populate it inside onCreate or in a initializer block. In this way the array list will be created only once and not every time you call `locateFromString`.

```
public void locateFromString(View view) {
    hideSoftKeyboard(view);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    String searchString = tv.getText().toString();

    ArrayList<String> thePlaces = new ArrayList<>();
    thePlaces.add("Thirsty Monk");
    thePlaces.add("Cocolino");
    thePlaces.add("The Melting Pot");
    thePlaces.add("De Danu");
    thePlaces.add("Carciuma");
    thePlaces.add("Boca");
    thePlaces.add("Bar Acasa");


    if (thePlaces.contains(searchString)) {
        //call goToLocation
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "There is no " + searchString + " subscribed to this app!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: ArrayList<String> thePlaces = new ArrayList<>();
        thePlaces.add("Thirsty Monk");
        thePlaces.add("Cocolino");
        thePlaces.add("The Melting Pot");
        thePlaces.add("De Danu");
        thePlaces.add("Carciuma");
        thePlaces.add("Boca");
        thePlaces.add("Bar Acasa"); I have changed to ArrayList like above. Where should I put then the code that you suggested as I cannot make it work?

Comment: Does the `searchString` represent the user input? If so, put it just below `searchString` initialization in the `locateFromString` method.

Comment: I have tried that but still the same result. I am new with this and I am sure it's a simple thing, but I do not know exactly how to do it. The concepts are not perfectly clear in my head. Is there a way now to show again my code so you can have a look?

Comment: So the method locateFromString will get the text into searchString, then I have to check if the searchString is found or not in my array. If it is I should use the gotoLocation method, if it's not I should provide a Toast message...

Comment: I have made thePlaces an instance variable and I populated it inside the onCreate. Exactly after the declaration of searchString I added the code that you provided. but te app crashes....FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick

Comment: I'm imagining that the app crashes because of the tv.getText() that may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException' so I would need some conditionals for tv.getText()?

Comment: Can you also show your layout xml with the TextView?

Comment: I have updated with the xml. I have also an update in the java related to the autocomplete field , but that should not influence the reason why the app crashes.

Comment: I know that my questions can be stupid to you but I am sure that you could help me with this:-)

Comment: I have posted the log also

Comment: `thePlaces.contains(searchString)` this line causes a null pointer exception because `thePlaces` is not initialized. Make sure that you initialize `thePlaces` before calling `contains()` or at least add a null check  `if (thePlaces != null)`

Comment: But if I add before the onCreate method ArrayList<String> thePlaces; doesnt that means that the the Places is initialized for the whole activity?

Comment: no, that means that you declared it as a instance variable. Initialize it inside onCreate like this `thePlaces = new ArrayList<>();` then populate it with your data.